# Duplicate a file in github webpage

Tags: github

I want to know if there is a way to duplicate a file in a repository using only the github web interface.

For example suppose that I have a repository called RepoA, inside I have a file called fileA and I want to create a fileB that is a copy of fileA but that it is now completely independent of what happends with fileA. fileA might be a template of a file to give an example.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can browse the file you want to duplicate, you can copy its content, you can create a new file and you can paste what you copied. So yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing that I know through the GitWeb interface.

You could script that with GitHub API call in order to:

- [get a blob](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/) from repoA
- transform it
- [create a blob](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/blobs/#create-a-blob) on repoB